# The files are on the clouds but Ubuntu One is not synchronising some of them

Tags: 12.04, sync

As mentionned [here](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-can-i-force-ubuntu-one-to-sync-my-files/) I've even tried to disconnect and reconnect but some files (all of them are LibreOffice files) are still not synchonised. What to do?

I'm on 12.04

Comment: How many files do you have in the cloud? Have you exceeded your allowance?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with Ubuntu One file synchronization. Seems to be ongoing despite some improvements, if you wait long enough they should eventually synch.
See the current notice on this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status#Files

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already wait 6 days. Somethings else must be wrong. And on the U1 application it's said that all files are sync which is not the case

Comment: And I've only 1% of my space used

Comment: Is anybody here ?
I've even remove this computer and install it again.
Nothing to do

Comment: Is anybody here ?
I've even remove this computer and install it again.
But no way
- All the files are on the cloud. I see them and have the hability to download by web interface
- The U1 application said that all files are syncs
- But only some of them on my desktop folder 

Any idea how to solve that (without going to Dropbox) ?